# Replace empty alt in wordpress post content with filter

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress

I need to replace empty image alt in wordpress post content with  image file name

I'm working on this function at the moment, please look at the comments:

```
// replace empty alt
function replace_empty_alt($content){
    if (is_single()) {        
        // searching in content text like src="post_image.jpg" alt="" 
        $newAlt = preg_match_all('/[^\/]+(?=\.[^\/.]* alt="")/', $content, $matches);
        // extracting image names
        foreach ( $matches as $match) { 
            $imageNames = implode(',', $matches[0]);
        }
        // convert in array of ImageNames
        $imageNamesNew = explode(',', $urls);

        // foreach ImageName do a replace in content
        foreach ((array) $imageNamesNew as $imageNameNew) {
            $content = str_replace('alt=""', 'alt="'.$imageNameNew.'"', $content );

        }
        return $content;
    }
}

add_filter('the_content', 'replace_empty_alt');
```

Basically what I need to do is to replace any empty alt in post content with exctrated image name.
At the moment it partially works, but I get the same $imageNameNew for any empty alt.

Something like:

```
<img class="size-full aligncenter" src="image-name1.jpg" alt="image-name1" width="799" height="449">

<img class="size-full aligncenter" src="image-name2.jpg" alt="image-name1" width="799" height="449">

<img class="size-full aligncenter" src="image-name3.jpg" alt="image-name1" width="799" height="449">
```

While I want to get a correct replace like:

```
<img class="size-full aligncenter" src="image-name1.jpg" alt="image-name1" width="799" height="449">

<img class="size-full aligncenter" src="image-name2.jpg" alt="image-name2" width="799" height="449">

<img class="size-full aligncenter" src="image-name3.jpg" alt="image-name3" width="799" height="449">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't use WordPress and don't know what helper functions it can offer, but you should use a proper DOM parser, not regex.

Using DOMDocument and Xpath makes a very clean, readable, maintainable solution.

The XPath query finds img tags (with an empty alt attribute) on any level in the document.  Inside the `foreach()` trim the file extension from the src value and apply it as the new alt value.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/IIBG1))

```
$html = <<<HTML
<body>
<img class="size-full aligncenter" src="image-name1.jpg" alt="" width="799" height="449">

<img class="size-full aligncenter" src="image-name2.jpg" alt="" width="799" height="449">

<img class="size-full aligncenter" src="image-name3.jpg" alt="" width="799" height="449">
</body>
HTML;

$dom = new DOMDocument; 
$dom->loadHTML($html, LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED | LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
foreach ($xpath->query('//img[@alt=""]') as $img) {
    $img->setAttribute(
        'alt',
        pathinfo(
            $img->getAttribute('src'),
            PATHINFO_FILENAME
        )
    );
}
echo $dom->saveHTML();
```

Comment: Thank you Mike,
I've never used a DOM parser with wordpress.
But it works great!! Thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the final working code for wp, based on mickmackusa solution:

```
function dom_empty_alt($content)
{
    // replace only for posts
    if (is_single()) {

        $dom = new DOMDocument();
        // set errors level
        $internalErrors = libxml_use_internal_errors(true);

        $content = mb_convert_encoding($content, 'HTML-ENTITIES', "UTF-8");

        $dom->loadHTML($content);
        // Restore errors level
        libxml_use_internal_errors($internalErrors);
        $xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
        foreach ($xpath->query('//img[@alt=""]') as $img) {
            $img->setAttribute('alt', pathinfo($img->getAttribute('src'), PATHINFO_FILENAME));
        }
        return $dom->saveHTML();
    } else {
        return $content;
    }
}

add_filter('the_content', 'dom_empty_alt', 20);
```

Comment: I've just read [in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72885483/accessibility-wordpress-add-alt-to-all-images-img-if-alt-is-missing#comment128735075_72885483) that WP6 has a new, relevant feature. https://make.wordpress.org/core/2022/04/27/new-filter-to-modify-content-images-in-wordpress-6-0/